# algorithm to split planning path from n gps points

Tags: c++, algorithm, planning

I currently have a final project on building a ground control station for a lakebed topographic survey vessel.  I want to build an algorithm to divide (grid) n Gps points into planning paths like the image above.  I got it from Measure Ground Control software, my algorithm requirements are similar.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwSfN.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yp08.jpg)
Picture from software Measure Ground Control.

i have succeeded for 4 gps points case, but not in case of more points. Can someone give me advide keywords or documentation on this. thank you

code 4 point, i code it in ESP32:

```
double get_target_list (int i, int _step_no, double _target_1, double _target_2, double _target_3, double _target_4){
    double _target_list = 0;
    int k_int = 0;
    int mod_4 = 0;
    k_int = i/4;
    mod_4 = i%4;

    if (mod_4 == 0)
        _target_list = get_target((2*k_int), _step_no, _target_1, _target_2);

    if (mod_4 == 1)
        _target_list = get_target((2*k_int+1), _step_no, _target_1, _target_2);

    if (mod_4 == 2)
        _target_list = get_target((2*k_int), _step_no, _target_4, _target_3);

    if (mod_4 == 3)
        _target_list = get_target((2*k_int+1), _step_no, _target_4, _target_3);

    return _target_list;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking for, but you might opt to 1. compute the smallest rectangle encompassing the `n` gps points and 2. call `get_target_list` on its four corners. This should provide you with a 'planning path' that in general will not be the most efficient but gets you started and which allows for certain perturbations and imprecisions among the gps point set.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I understand you.  for example we have 5 points, we will find the smallest rectangle passing through these 5 points, but we need to remove more points outside the contour of these 5 points, do you have any suggestions or keywords for the problem? .